# Add hours to the present date with groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I need some help on how to add hours to the present date, following is my code to add days to the present date.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def today = new Date()
def laterDate = today + 29 // adding 29 days
laterDate = laterDate + Duration.parse("PT1H")
def dda = laterDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd 17:00:00")
log.info dda
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easy if you use `TimeCategory` as shown below. Just add `2.hour and 30.minutes` to the date like the natural language and apply `+`.

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def twoAndHalfHourFromNow = new Date() + 2.hour + 30.minutes 
    log.info twoAndHalfHourFromNow.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
}
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/3AYmjb)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Rao, it worked thank you, can you also advise if we can add the GMT time tot he present date.

Comment: @peter, The original question got answered, appreciate if accepted as answer. Regarding your question from comment, you want to add the the local timezone or GMT always?

Comment: @peter, can you try with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ` format and see if that is what you are looking after?